# How to tell what PHP 7 version is installed, and how to update it to latest version?

Tags: package-management, php

I'm using Vagrant box (Homestead actually) with Ubuntu. When I use PHP 5.6 box for

```
php -v
```

I'm getting:

```
PHP 5.6.13-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+3 (cli)
```

so it's clear that's PHP 5.6.13.

But when running box with PHP 7 I'm getting:

```
PHP 7.0.0-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli) ( NTS )
```

and I'm really not sure if it's PHP 7.0 or if it's PHP 7.0.2 (I don't understand what `-2` is here in PHP version).

I'm running `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.19.0-25-generic x86_64)` in this box

When I run:

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep php
```

I'm getting:

```
php-common                                      install
php-curl                                        install
php-gd                                          install
php-imap                                        install
php-mysql                                       install
php-pgsql                                       install
php-sqlite3                                     install
php7.0-cli                                      install
php7.0-common                                   install
php7.0-curl                                     install
php7.0-dev                                      install
php7.0-fpm                                      install
php7.0-gd                                       install
php7.0-imap                                     install
php7.0-json                                     install
php7.0-mysql                                    install
php7.0-opcache                                  install
php7.0-pgsql                                    install
php7.0-sqlite3                                  install
```

When I run:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade php-common
```

I'm getting at the moment:

```
php-common is already the newest version.
php-common set to manually installed.
```

So the question is - if it's PHP 7.0 and not 7.0.2 how can I easy update to latest 7.0.2 or maybe it's not available yet as package for Ubuntu?

**EDIT**

As suggested I've run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

There was info about installing PHP 7.0.2 however when I run `php -v` I'm still getting:

```
PHP 7.0.0-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 (cli)
```

And now when I run

```
 sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I'm getting:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libssl-dev nfs-common openssl php7.0-cli php7.0-dev php7.0-fpm
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

And when I run:

```
apt-cache policy php7.0-cli
```

I'm getting:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ apt-cache policy php7.0-cli
php7.0-cli:
  Installed: 7.0.0-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  Candidate: 7.0.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
  Version table:
     7.0.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php-7.0/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 *** 7.0.0-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Package search using `php7` keyword returns nothing for Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty).  PHP 7 only exists for 16.04 (xenial), according to [this search result](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=php7).

Comment: @clearkimura You should read my answer - you'll see it's from a PPA and not a package in the standard repositories.

Comment: If `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` doesn't solve your problem please attach output of `apt-cache policy php7.0-cli`.

Comment: @oerdnj Please look at my edit

Comment: Ok, now try `apt-get dist-upgrade` and if that doesn't work, it's some vagrant configuration you are using. But hey, this is really basics of a system administration, you should have done this before you came here to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First part, what's installed.

This all goes back to package versioning schemes, and why you're getting confused.  So, lets dissect it into its individual parts.  Assuming it conforms to typical Debian versioning and such, then...

Take php7 you stated:

```
PHP 7.0.0-2+deb.sury.org~trusty+1
```

This string is dissected as follows:

- `PHP` = the software name
- `7.0.0` = the version of that software (from PHP's own versioning schemes)
- `-2` = the Package Revision number - that is, how many different packaging changes have been done - this would be the "Second Package" which means they made changes to the packaging or applied patches through `quilt` in the second version.
- `+deb.sury.org` indicates the repository source - it's from `deb.sury.org` repos, which are actually PPAs running on Launchpad, with packages made by the one who runs the `deb.sury.org` website.
- `~trusty+1` - This indicates additional version specific changes done for the repository - this is an Ubuntu Trusty, package, and likely is either the first or second revision of the package (depending on if they ever had `+0` or not) specific for Trusty.

**TL;DR:** This is a PHP 7.0.0 package, but it has had a couple of revisions since the initial PHP 7.0.0 package.

---

Second part, how to get PHP 7.0.2.

The repository you are using is a PPA - likely [this one](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+index?batch=75&memo=75&start=75).

It was informed to me that 7.0.2 is available and you need to run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.  That should put you on the right versions.  If it doesn't, then try using `apt-get dist-upgrade` as there may be other dependencies that need added and the upgrade was held back because of that.

Comment: JFTR; the PPA is already at PHP 7.0.2 since 2016-01-14, so the thing he is missing is plain `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and OPs PHP 5.6 also looks outdated.

Comment: Please look at my edit

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek go see mine.

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` solved the issue in this case. I have now `PHP 7.0.2-4+deb.sury.org~trusty+1`. Thank you for your help